# Can I detect in Powershell that I am running in VS Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I would like to modify the standard PowerShell profile in Windows if the Powershell opens inside VS Code integrated terminal (when you are editing e.g. python scripts in VS Code, rather than PS scripts, which opens the ISE profile in any case).

Is there some environmental variable that gets set by the integrated PowerShell? Or is there some way of opening Powershell with a particular profile, instead of the default?

Thanks

Comment: As an aside: You can reconfigure your file associations to open PowerShell scripts (`*.ps1`) in Visual Studio code too (e.g., via File Explorer), which I recommend, given that the [ISE is obsolescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and has and never will have support for PowerShell _Core_ (v6+).

Answer (score 29):

VS Code creates an environment variable named `TERM_PROGRAM`. You can check it for a value of `vscode`, something like this:

```
if($env:TERM_PROGRAM -eq 'vscode') {
  # do some stuff...
}
```

Comment: That's indeed the most reliable and cross-platform solution - surprising, though, given that `TERM_PROGRAM` is a standard environment variable only on _macOS_. But, as you state, VSCode creates it _on demand_ on Windows and Linux (and modifies it on macOS), along with the other normally-Mac-only `TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION` (but _not_ also `TERM_PROGRAM_SESSION`).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to check if you're running within `PowerShell Integrated Console` (ships with PowerShell extension) under vscode and not just any powershell console running under vscode, you can:

```
if ($Host.Name -eq 'Visual Studio Code Host') {
  Write-Output 'PowerShell Integrated Console'
}
```

This is meaningful to detect because it is the only powershell console host that provided full debugger support (eg. break on exception experience) and debugger integration with vscode.

You said you're into modifying profile when running within vscode, then you should check (again with PowerShell integrated console which ships with PoweShell extension):

```
PS> $PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost
C:\Users\username\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1

PS> $PROFILE.AllUsersCurrentHost
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1
```

If people are working on PowerShell code within Visual Studio Code, then why they would NOT install PowerShell extension which ships with a specific console that fully integrates with Visual Studio code and on the top of that, provides you a profile file specifically geared towards Visual Studio code?